# Custom DIV to show extra information

Tags: css

How can i display stuff like that

[image]

The red div it's css or js or a plugin ?

Comment: It's can be done with only CSS, it can be done with a self-written JS, and it can be done by a JS plugin.

Comment: useful link http://www.css3shapes.com/

Comment: this is Jquery validation-plugin

Comment: thanks @Beginner for the link but in facebook i can't found this css because the div disappear quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Stuff like that" is called Tooltip.

I think this will be useful: https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

or

just google "tooltip jquery plugin"...

Comment: thanks @Kylie_Lovelace **Tooltip** finally. the other are not good with beginner like me.

Comment: Glad to help.
Sure, you can use just css.